Regex to match list of words
I want to extract countries from a list of files names. The countries can appear multiple times, separated by a comma and space.
My regex (used in Powershell 7):
$regex = "^[^\(]* \(([\b(USA|Japan|Europe|Germany|Canada)\b,\s]*)\).*$"
if ($name -match $regex) {
    #...
}

(list of countries shortened)
Example data:
3-D Genesis (USA) (Proto)
Wallaby!! - Usagi no Kuni no Kangaroo Race (Japan) (Wii U Virtual Console)
UWOL - Quest for Money (World) (v1.1) (Aftermarket) (Unl)
Super Star Soldier (USA, Europe) (Wii U Virtual Console)
Soldier Blade (USA, Europe) (Wii U Virtual Console)
Mein Weg (USA, Germany) (En)
Challenge (Canada)

But Powershell seems to ignore the word boundaries?
Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              USA) (Proto
0                              3-D Genesis (USA) (Proto)

Even weirder, given the above sample data, Regexr matches the first example, but doesn't seem to understand the end of line at the "mein weg" example, and matches the following line


maybe because \b is within character class?

check your flags on regexr, you should use the multiline flag too. also if you just want the country and not the language you should use a lazy match *?

your pattern should be lazy matching, ....\b,\s]*?

Square brackets match only single characters, not strings.

What version of powershell and what command are you using to get the matches?

@sirtao I've added the info - Powershell 7 using the "-match" operator, maybe it's not ideal...

The pattern provided by Kenzo Staelens should work properly. Is that pattern failing for you? If so, please add also the code to generate your list

like mentioned in comments already a few pointers should be given

square brackets only match literal characters: use regular brackets instead

you should use lazy matching to stop at the first closing bracket

you're missing the multiline flag to match every line instead of everything together
/^[^\(]* \(((?:\b(USA|Japan|Europe|Germany|Canada)\b|\s|,)*?)\).*$/gm




The multiline flag is set, which is why I find it weird that it matches multiple lines. Maybe I did something wrong with my copy/paste into Regexr and mixed Linux and Windows-style line breaks. Thanks for the regex, it seems to be working better (but I suspect the "-match" PS operator makes weird things)

Nevermind it works perfectly, I just forgot to properly process the result. Thanks!

what is this app to check matching ?
